# Custom xib inside another xib not being sized properly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xib

To get started, here is the hierarchy of my views:

```
- Table view
-- Table view cell (loaded from custom xib)
--- Collection view
---- Collection view cell (loaded from custom xib)
----- Custom view (loaded from custom xib)
```

What I'm having trouble with is that last view, the custom view, that I'm loading into the collection view cell as a custom xib. For some reason, it isn't being sized properly:

[image]

As you can see, the view has a giant white space above it, instead of filling out the cell properly. Funnily enough, if I scroll down the table view a bit, and then scroll back up, it displays at it should:

[image]

Here is part of my collection view code:

```
// I use this to size the collection view cells to be of 16:9 ratio, nothing crazy
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    // Get the width of the screen
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

    let imageWidth = width
    let imageHeight = imageWidth / (16 / 9)

    self.postMediaHeight = imageHeight

    return CGSize(width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight)
}

// Here I initialize the cell
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PostMediaCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as? PostMediaCollectionViewCell else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of PostMediaCollectionViewCell.")
    }

    let media = post.images[indexPath.row]

    cell.initialize()

    return cell
}
```

Here is my collection view cell class, `PostMediaCollectionViewCell`. Nothing out of the ordinary:

```
class PostMediaCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var container: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var moreView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var moreViewLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myCustomView: MyCustomView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    func initialize() {
        //
    }
}
```

And lastly, here is my class for `MyCustomView`:

```
class MyCustomView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet var rootView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var videoView: VideoView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initialize()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initialize()
    }

    func initialize() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyCustomView", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(rootView)
        rootView.frame = self.bounds
        rootView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    }
}
```

I've made sure that I have my constraints set right in my xibs, so auto layout should be working, but it's clearly not:

PostMediaCollectionViewCell xib:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQLpj.png

MyCustomView xib:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpSi0.png

So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Add a breakpoint on line         `rootView.frame = self.bounds` and check `self.bounds` values. If is the value different from the value after scrolling, you should change your `awakeFromNib` method.

lass PostMediaCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var container: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var moreView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var moreViewLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var myCustomView: MyCustomView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    self.myCustomView.frame = self.bounds 
    self.myCustomView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

}

func initialize() {
    //
}
```

}

Comment: You're right in that the `bounds` values are different when I scroll down and back up, but your solution didn't seem to change anything for me. :/

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution to this, but I don't know why it works and whether or not it's the best way of solving it, so I'm looking for input.

If I modify my `PostMediaCollectionViewCell` class to include `layoutIfNeeded()` in the initialization function, it works:

```
class PostMediaCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var container: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var moreView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var moreViewLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myCustomView: MyCustomView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    func initialize() {
        layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

But I don't understand why. Can someone explain?